# Authenticate REST API written in Go running on AWS ECS Fargate behind AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, go, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am creating few REST endpoints using Go and GIN that will be called by few services. Planning to run this in ECS Fargate behind an application load balancer. I can't use API Gateway because of the request size limitation. I am not sure what is the best way to protect my endpoints. it will be great if you could share any blogs/ guides/ best practices in the answer as I'm pretty new to building REST APIs, Go and GIN.

For all other services we use cognito user pool with client credential oauth flow with API Gateway for authentication.  So it will be a better to use cognito user pool

Comment: ALB also supports Cognito https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html

Comment: I tried that, ALB only supports Cognito with authorisation code grand OAuth flow. which needs user interaction, to enter user name and password. I want to authenticate services using client credential flow.

Comment: I think you'll have to integrate with Cognito at your application level then.